# What is causing this sedum's leaves to curl and etiolate?

Tags: diagnosis, succulents, sunlight, sedum

A few months ago I took a sedum from a soil plot where they were being used as a ground cover. I think it was *Sedum ewersii*, *Sedum sieboldii*, *Sedum cauticola* or a species very closely related. I potted the sedum in cactus potting soil with some perlite and put it on a shelf underneath my grow lights.

A few weeks ago I noticed a few of the leaves were dramatically curled over. Then shoots and more leaves began to grow. These new growths appear curled, elongated, and a few branches almost look etiolated. All of these symptoms are captured in the first image below and can be compared to the plant's original appearance after transplanting in the second.

[image: Sedum's leaves are curled, stems etiolated.]
[image: Sedum before symptoms, after transplanting]

As side notes:

- Notice the longest axillary branch on the left. I cut off the leaf that shared this branch's node because of how curled it looked, thinking the leaf was releasing some sort of hormone. I don't know if this is the case though.
- I originally thought the shoot at the base of the plant in the first image was a basal shoot but it just appears to be an axillary branch (just from speculation, though).

What is wrong with my sedum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely its being indoors - if its Sedum ewersii, these are deciduous, so it would normally be resting right now if you're in the Northern hemisphere. They grow best outdoors, in normal weather conditions, which is what they're adapated for, so this plant may be finding it hard to cope being placed under lights in the middle of winter inside. Transition shock alone could produce the symptoms you've been seeing on the longer topgrowth.